# UITableViewController's view has wrong frame when pushed into an embedded UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a container view controller with a fixed height view at the top and an embedded UINavigationController below it. The container view that embeds the UINavigationController has a Top Space constraint to the fixed height view, and a Bottom Space constraint to the top layout guide. This results in the navigation controller's height being 599 on an iPhone 6 (the fixed height view at the top occupies the remaining 68 points). I've verified the height of the navigtation controller's view at runtime in lldb.

However, when I push a UITableViewController into the embedded UINavigationController, the height of the UITableViewController's table view is 667 points, not 599 as I would have expected. I can work around this by setting a bottom content inset of 68 points, but I'd like to avoid this if possible.

What do I need to do to ensure that the height of the views of controller's pushed into this UINavigationController match the height of the navigation controller?

Comment: At what point are you determining the table view has the wrong height? Is it correct by the time `viewDidAppear:` is called?

Comment: I've tried outputting both at the end of viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear in the table view controller, and it's too tall in both places.

Comment: FYI, I added this line of code to the navigation controller delegate's navigationController(_:willShowViewController:animated) method for the embedded navigation controller, and it seems to correct the issue, but not sure if there's a better solution: viewController.view.frame = navigationController.view.bounds